# Js for loop - help needed

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have created a basic program that asks a customer...
**How many tacos the customer wants to order**

I want the for loop that is inside the function **place_order** to console.log the pharase...

Your **x amount** of tacos are being prepared.

However, if the customer ordered 3 tacos; I want the message to be console.loged 3 times.
If the customer typed 8 tacos - I want the message to be console.logged for 8 times.

**How many tacos would you like to order**

Customer inputs: 3

Output: **your 3 tacos are being prepared**
**your 3 tacos are being prepared**
**your 3 tacos are being prepared**

```js
confirm = window.confirm("Hey there! Would you like to order some tacos?");
prompt = window.prompt("How many tacos would you like to order? (Maximum amount is 99 tacos")

console.log(confirm)
console.log(prompt)

function place_order(){
    console.log("Your order will contain:  " + prompt + "   tacos!!!");  //This line confirms your order.
    console.log("Your total is: " + prompt*5 + " USD."); //This line gives you the total $ spent.
    for (let i = prompt; i <= prompt; i++){
        console.log("Your  " + prompt + "  tacos are being prepared ");
    }
}

place_order()
```

Comment: `for (let i = prompt; i <= prompt; i++){` loops from (eg) 3 to 3. You'll need `for (let i = 0; i < prompt; i++){`

Comment: What sense does it make to print the exact same message multiple times?

Answer (score -1):

You should start the index from 1, as you are starting it from the prompt input, that is why it is not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).